# AngularJS $compile evaluating scope attributes instead of binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sure I've messed something up in the chain but here goes:

I have a bunch of "widget form" directives which I need to conditionally display based on which widget type the user selects. For example, if the user selects the bar chart I need to display the  directive. I've achieved that using $compile which is a fairly simple directive. What I'm struggling with is trying to pass the result of the bar chart form out.

The order goes like this:

- Open modal
- Pick widget type (modal has an ng-switch which will display the next directive)
- $compile `< widget-form-compiler widgetType="$ctrl.widgetType" output="$ctrl.output" >`
- Which should render `< bar-chart-form output="$ctrl.output" >`
- But instead it renders as `< bar-chart-form output="'undefined'" >`

The "output" is being evaluated instead of being passed through as a reference I think.

I'd really appreciate any help on this. This is the last chain in the link.

If the code example below is not detailed enough I can make a JSFiddle to demonstrate my problem if necessary.

***UPDATE:*** if I change the widget-compiler directive to this: output="$parent.$ctrl.output" I can access it in the controller it was called from. Of course, this makes sense, but how can I dynamically do this?

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('optimizeDashboards')
    .directive('widgetFormCompiler', widgetFormCompiler);

  widgetFormCompiler.$inject = ['$compile'];

  function widgetFormCompiler($compile) {
    // Usage: Generates a widget.
    var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        widgetType: '=',
        output: '='
      }
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      var convertedWidgetType = scope.widgetType.widgetName.toDash() + "-form";
      var generatedTemplate = '<' + convertedWidgetType + ' output="\'' + scope.output + '\'" widget-type="\'' + scope.widgetType + '\'"></' + convertedWidgetType + '>';
      element.append($compile(generatedTemplate)(scope));
    }
  }

})();


(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('optimizeDashboards')
    .component('barChartForm', {
      template: ` * The form is pretty big plus is not the issue so I have removed it from this example for the sake of brevity * `,
      controller: BarChartFormController,
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      bindings: {
        output: '='
      }
    });


  BarChartFormController.$inject = ['$timeout', 'languageService', 'barChartFormService', '$uibModalStack', 'widgetFormModalService'];

  function BarChartFormController($timeout, languageService, barChartFormService, $uibModalStack, widgetFormModalService) {

    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.$onInit = function() {
      $ctrl.translation = languageService;
      $ctrl.widgetObject = {};
      $ctrl.widgetObject.parameters = {};
    };

    $ctrl.cancelModal = cancelModal;
    $ctrl.saveWidget = saveWidget;

    function cancelModal() {
      $uibModalStack.dismissAll('cancel');
    }

    function saveWidget() {
      // $ctrl.widgetObject is the final object processed by the form. if console logged in this function it outputs when submit is pressed.
      $ctrl.output = $ctrl.widgetObject;
    }

  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your view model manually into your compile scope. Currently `$ctrl.output` is undefined thats why it does result in a `undefined` string after compile. The compile function itself does not evaluate your params. It just tries to compile it. In that way `undefined` params result in an `undefined` string output.

#### View

```
<widget-form-compiler widgetType="$ctrl.widgetType" 
                      view-model="$ctrl" 
                      output="$ctrl.output">
</widget-form-compiler>
```

#### Directive

```
function widgetFormCompiler($compile) {
    // Usage: Generates a widget.
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            widgetType: '=',
            output: '=',
            viewModel: '='
        }
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$ctrl = scope.viewModel;

        var convertedWidgetType = scope.widgetType.widgetName.toDash() + "-form";
        var generatedTemplate = '<' + convertedWidgetType + ' output="\'' + scope.output + '\'" widget-type="\'' + scope.widgetType + '\'"></' + convertedWidgetType + '>';
        element.append($compile(generatedTemplate)(scope));
    }
}
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g0xckta/) or [debug demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmmnop2m/)**

Comment: Ah, fantastic. Thanks so much! :D